# pytest - specify log level from the CLI command running the tests

Tags: python, logging, pytest, command-line-interface

my team and I are using Pytest + Jenkins to automate our product testing. we have been using the standard Logging lib of python to get proper log messages during testing, before and after each test etc. we have multiple layers of logging, we log out ERROR, WARNING, INFO and DEBUG. the default value for our logger is INFO. we create the logger object in the primary setup of the tests, and pass it down to each object created, so all our logs go to the same logger.

so far when we are developing a new feature or test, we are working in DEBUG mode locally, and change it back to INFO when submitting new code to our SVN, but i am trying to add option to change logging level using the CLI, but i haven't found anything easy to implement. I've considered using Fixtures, but from what i understand those are only for the tests themselves, and not for the setup/tear-down phases, and the log is created regard less of the tests.
any hack or idea on how to add a Pytest option to the CLI command to support changing logging level?

Comment: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/logging.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Pytest 3.5 introduced a parameter

```
pytest --log-cli-level=INFO
```

For versions prior to 3.5 you can combine [pytest commandline options](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#pass-different-values-to-a-test-function-depending-on-command-line-options) and the [python loglevel from commandline example](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file) to do the following:

Add the following to `conftest.py`:

```
import pytest
import logging


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--log", action="store", default="WARNING", help="set logging level"
    )


@pytest.fixture
def logger():
    loglevel = pytest.config.getoption("--log")
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    numeric_level = getattr(
        logging,
        loglevel.upper(),
        None
    )
    if not isinstance(numeric_level, int):
        raise ValueError('Invalid log level: %s' % loglevel)

    logger.setLevel(numeric_level)
    return logger
```

and then request the `logger` fixture in your tests

```
def test_bla(logger):
    assert True
    logger.info("True is True")
```

Then run pytest like

```
py.test --log INFO
```

to set the log level to `INFO`.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: not exactly, but your example did give me the right idea. i'm creating the logger object at the setup_class of the suite, so i didn't use fixtures, i just used the example you gave me of how to use the pytest_addoption method, to add logging level to the pytest CLI command. i didn't realize it was that simple, and got lost in fixtures and hooks when reading in the pytest doc.

Answer (score 34):

Try `--log-cli-level=INFO`

like:

```
pytest -vv -s --log-cli-level=INFO --log-cli-format="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)8s] %(message)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)s)" --log-cli-date-format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" ./test_file.py
```

Comment: `py.test: error: unrecognized arguments: --log-cli-level=DEBUG`

Answer (score 31):

This is now built into pytest. Just add '--log-level=' to the command line when running your test. For example:

```
pytest --log-level=INFO
```

Documentation updates can be found here: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/logging.html

Comment: Thanks, this worked better than `--log-cli-level`, disabling third-party modules logging.

Comment: Oddly, this did not work for me, both my library and 3rd party.