# Configure logging for pytest on a per-module basis

Tags: python-3.x, logging, pytest

I have a `pytest.ini` file with the following contents:

```
[pytest]
log_level=WARN
log_cli_level=WARN
log_file_level=WARN
log_auto_indent=on
```

This works for turning off all logging that is below the warning level.  Is there a way to turn up logging for a single module?  Generally, I would like the module that I am actively debugging at info or debug, but the only way that I see to do that is manually set that in the code or replace all of the `WARN` with `DEBUG`, which gives me lots of output from modules I don't care about.

I found [pytest: selective log levels on a per-module basis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52086974/pytest-selective-log-levels-on-a-per-module-basis), which seems to indicate that you cannot do it from the CLI.  Config files often offer more options (especially for something which could be as complicated as this) but I am not finding anything about it in the docs.

I am using python 3.7.6 and pytest 7.0.1, but am happy to upgrade to a newer stable version if that provides a good solution.

Comment: I may be missing something, but why not set the appropriate levels within your ini file and limit the pytest run to the module you're actively debugging?

Comment: Usually, the module that I am testing calls other modules.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility to solve this problem is to use the [`caplog`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/logging.html#caplog-fixture) fixture as an [`autouse=True`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#autouse-fixtures-fixtures-you-don-t-have-to-request) fixture, i.e., a kind of hidden fixture that is only used for setup/teardown without the necessity to add it to the argument lists of each and every test case:

```py
import logging
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def change_default_log_level_fixture(caplog: pytest.LogCaptureFixture):
    with caplog.at_level(logging.INFO):
        yield
```

This snippet can for instance be added to a test module, which would mean that all tests in that module run at the modified log level.

Alternatively it can be placed in a `conftest.py`, which allows to change the default for an entire (tree of) test modules. For instance, placing it like in the following example would mean that tests in `bar` use the default log level of `WARNING` whereas tests in `foo` would use a log level of `INFO`.

```
.
└── tests
    ├── bar
    │   └── test_bar.py
    └── foo
        ├── conftest.py
        └── test_foo.py
```